# IFormFile as aproperty of Class in Web API

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am sending file from jquery ajax to asp.net core web api, but web api accepts every property as null.

```
public class YuklenecekDosya 
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; }
    public string TableAdi { get; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromForm]YuklenecekDosya File)
    {
        var file = File.File;

        if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            return Content("Yuklenecek fayl Secmemisiniz!");

        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Dosyalar");
            string fullfilepath = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }



            using (var fs=new FileStream(fullfilepath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fs);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(file);
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

and clintside ajax code is as below:

```
let f=new FormData();
    f.append('File',$('input').files[0]);


    let File={
        File:f,
        iD:2,
        tableAdi:"Table1"
    };

    $.ajax({
        method:'Post',
        url:'api/Values/Upload',
        data:File,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    }).then(model=>{
        console.log(model);
    });
```

when i debug it, everything in YuklenecekDosya parameter gives null.
i cant figure out where is the problem. 
by the way, when i try parameter as just IFormFile, not YuklenecekDosya, it works,but when i take IFormFile as a property of YuklenecekDosya parameter, it gives all the properties null

Comment: Try: `f.append('ID',2);` and `f.append('TableAdi','test');` and `$.ajax({
        method:'Post',
        url:'api/Values/Upload',
        data: f,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    }).then(model=>{
        console.log(model);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

So the `$ajax` call will be:

```
let f = new FormData();
f.append('File', $('input').files[0]);
f.append('ID', 2);
f.append('TableAdi', 'Table1');

$.ajax({
    method: 'Post',
    url: 'api/Values/Upload',
    data: f, <-- Here pass f
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
}).then(model => {
    console.log(model);
});
```

Comment: Nope. Case-sensitivity is not an issue.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Just tested! Exactly! I came across with this case sensitive related issue when I was working with WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is you doesn't provide `set` implementation on your property , please modify your `YuklenecekDosya` class to :

```
public class YuklenecekDosya
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TableAdi { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify your javascript code like :

```
let f = new FormData();
f.append('File', $('input').files[0]);
f.append('ID', 2);
f.append('TableAdi', 'Table1');

$.ajax({
    method: 'Post',
    url: '../api/Values/Upload',
    data: f,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

}).then(model => {
    console.log(model);
});
```

In addition , if your markup is like :

```
<input type="file" name="files"  id="files" >
```

In javascript , you can get the file using :

```
let f = new FormData();
f.append('File', $('#files').get(0).files[0]);
```